# Posting an image to fan page album using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I have created an Facebook App. I need user to be able to post images to my facebook page's album through that App and for that I need to grab Access Token of the page. I can only get access token when I am logged in as an administrator of the page but if  I log in with other account I don't get the access token of the page (Even though I liked the page and installed the App). Code is below

```
$fanpage = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$pages_arr = array(
'access_token'=>$access_token,
'fields'=>'access_token' 
);

$page_token = $facebook->api('/'.$fanpage, 'get', $pages_arr);
$fanpage_token = $page_token['access_token'];

**//When logged in as admin of the page I get the token but I don't get the token if I am not //page admin**

echo $fanpage_token;

$file = "@".realpath("test.jpg");  
$args = array(
    'message' => 'test',
    'image' => $file,
    'aid' => $album_id,
    'no_story' => 1, 
    'access_token' => $fanpage_token  // note, we use the page token here
);

$photo = $facebook->api("/$album_id/photos", 'post', $args);
if( is_array( $photo ) && ! empty( $photo['id'] ) )
    echo 'Photo uploaded. Check it on Graph API Explorer. ID: ' . $photo['id'];
```

I asking for following permissions on App install

```
manage_notifications,user_photos,photo_upload,publish_stream,friends_photos,manage_pages
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is intended behaviour. The manage_pages permission gives access to pages which the user administrates. If you need other (non admin) users to upload to your page, you'll need to store a valid access token for the page in your app. Then, use the saved access token to upload the image provided by the user.

Comment: But the problem is access tokens expire after a while. Is there a way to prevent access token from expiring or can we get an access token that never expires? as far as I know offline access is also deprecated now.